# Can we get uniform distributions on infinite spaces by giving up infinite additivity

Tags: probability, measure-theory, philosophical, kolmogorov-axioms

I am wondering whether it is possible to translate the idea of drawing a number randomly from the set of all natural numbers. If we have infinite additivity as an axiom this obviously does not work. What I wonder however is whether giving up infinite additivity and only insisting on finite additivity allows us to work with this kind of situations. And furthermore I wonder how useful it would be to work within an axiomatization without infinite additivity.

Comment: Even with just finite additivity, what probability would a uniform distribution *necessarily* assign to each natural number?

Comment: the probability would of course be 0.

Comment: It seems that answers your question.

Comment: If the only events of interest are infinite sets of numbers (like even or odd) this can be useful, and maybe used in number theory. But you can never simulate from such a distribution, and never use with data, so far as data consists of individual numbers

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose? For the integers, say, you can assign every single integer probability zero, but the complete set $\mathbb{Z}$ probability one. This makes it finitely additive.

Various infinite sets could have finite probability, like the evens and the odds each probability $1/2$. But you cannot simulate from such a distribution, and it is not clear it is useful for anything, at least not in statistics.